# Make doesn't automatically invoke my "clean" target

Tags: makefile

I have seen similar questions, but in my case none of the answers given work. I have written the following Makefile:

```
# Compiler to use
CC = gcc

# flags to pass compiler
CFLAGS = -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Werror

# Name for the executable
EXE = cuaterniones

# space-separated list of header files
HDRS = cuaternion.h

# space-separated list of libraries, if any,
# each of which should be prefixed with -l
LIBS = -lm

# space-separated list of source files
SRCS = main.c cuaternion.c

# automatically generated list of object files
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

# default target
$(EXE): $(OBJS) $(HDRS) Makefile
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

# dependencies 
$(OBJS): $(HDRS) Makefile

# housekeeping
clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

As it can be inferred, I want to remove all object files after compiling. However, when I call make, the program is compiled, but object files are not removed. However, if I do: make clean, it works as expected. The thing is, I have seen that this should be automatic, if I call make it should automatically clean the files for me, and that is what I want. Moreover, I want to know why it is not working, what is my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it is unusual for `make clean` to not also remove the executable, as most people would expect it to do.  Perhaps you need a `clean-obj` target, or similar.  In any case, it is not automatic and you need to call it explicitly.  eg.:

```
$(EXE): $(OBJS) $(HDRS) Makefile
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LIBS)
    $(MAKE) clean
```

Here `$(MAKE)` evaluates to the make command used (usually 'make' but could be 'gmake' or something else). But, as mentioned above, the convention is that `make clean` should remove the executable, so you probably want to use a different name for a target that only removes object files.

Comment: So, the convention for clean is to remove everything, object code + executables?

Comment: The convention is that clean removes everything that other targets create.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't say anything, make only strives to make the first target, a.k.a. the default target.

Your `clean` target isn't the first target, isn't a dependency of the first target, and isn't a target from the command line, so make isn't instructed to go through it.

You *could* get it included in the default target by splitting them as such:

```
default: $(EXE) clean     # as a first target
```

But I wouldn't recommend it, it's not a dependency that makes sense, and it won't work at all if you try to run it in parallel.

I personally would just go for a workflow where I simply don't clean after build unless I specifically need to, in which case I'd likely use a canned `make && make clean` command line.

Another aproach would be to have the object files built as implicit intermediate targets—I think GNU make cleans those up automatically.